# .Net core 3 site hosting 404 errors

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core

I have a .Net core 3 website I am trying to host.  I have already successfully deployed one site and trying to deply a second site and having no luck.  If I point the folder of the working site at the new sites folder and I also share the application pool of the working site, it works, so I am 100% sure its an IIS configuration issue.  I'm getting 404 errors when I try to browse.  The only difference for the new site is it is on a different port and no certificate is installed, so maybe SSL code in my startup is having an effect

```
public class Startup
{

    private string path = string.Empty;
    private string connection = string.Empty;

    public class ErrorDetails
    {
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
        {
            options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status308PermanentRedirect;
            options.HttpsPort = 443;
        });

        //services.AddResponseCaching();
        services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;

        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options => {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Denied";
                    //options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                }); 
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        //app.UseResponseCaching();

        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

            //endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            //    name: "default",
            //    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseExceptionHandler(appError =>
        {
            appError.Run(async context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

                var contextFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

                var exceptionFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

                if (exceptionFeature != null)
                {
                    // Get which route the exception occurred at
                    string routeWhereExceptionOccurred = exceptionFeature.Path;

                    // Get the exception that occurred
                    Exception exceptionThatOccurred = exceptionFeature.Error;

                    Serilog.Log.Error($" Web API error in controller:{routeWhereExceptionOccurred}" + Environment.NewLine + exceptionThatOccurred.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + new String('-', 100));

                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDetails()
                    {
                        StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
                        Message = $"Unhandled exception at location:{routeWhereExceptionOccurred}, please see log files located in:{path} for details" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Exception:" + exceptionThatOccurred.ToString()

                    }.ToString());
                }

            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `services.AddHttpsRedirection` method will force the http request redirect to the https.

But if you don't bind the https in the IIS server that means there is no https url, so it will return 404 error.

To solve this issue, I suggest you could remove this method if you don't want to enable the https for the web application.